# Listview have onscrolll when have multiline text

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, textview

I have some problems if an item in a listview has a multi-line text.
Then there is a scroll-bar visible. But if the item in the listview has only one line it is working.

I try this:

http://www.journaldev.com/10444/android-custom-listview-non-scrollable

it's working but it takes a long time to run.

How to create Non Scrollable ListView?

Comment: So you want a non scrollable listview?

Comment: @MPhil yes ,i want it

Comment: And whats the exact problem with implementation from the link? What do you mean it takes a long time?